# Asynchronously posting to Azure Queues

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-queues

I try to enqueue messages in Azure Queues asynchronously like this:

```
private async Task EnqueueItemsAsync(IEnumerable<string> messages) {
            var tasks = messages.Select(msg => _queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(msg),
                null, null, null, null));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
```

If I get it right this says "start enqueuing one item after the other without waiting them to get posted, keep a reference for each task and then wait until all get posted".

This code works fine in most cases, but for a large number of items (5000), it starts enqueuing and then **throws a timeout exception** (after having enqueued ~3500 items).

I solved it by waiting each one to finish before continuing with the next one

```
private async Task EnqueueItemsAsync(IEnumerable<string> messages) {
            foreach (var message in messages) {
                await _queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(message), null, null, null, null);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone explain why this happened?

Exception:

> `System.AggregateException` which wraps many such exceptions:
>   `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)` Request Information RequestID: RequestDate: StatusMessage: <---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #1) Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The client could not
>   finish the operation within specified timeout. --->
>   System.TimeoutException: The client could not finish the operation
>   within specified timeout. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult
>   result)`.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? and which method? Post the exception name, message and stacktrace

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks for mentioning, just updated my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A queue in Azure is designed have a throughput of 2000 messages per second.

See: [Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/)

> When your application **reaches the limit** of what a partition can handle for your workload, Azure Storage will begin to return error code 503 (Server Busy) or error code 500 (**Operation Timeout**) responses. When this occurs, the application should use an exponential backoff policy for retries. The exponential backoff allows the load on the partition to decrease, and to ease out spikes in traffic to that partition.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this solves the riddle. So my first code runs the for loop in less than a second, starting 5000 post requests in less than a second which results timeout responses... seems reasonable

Comment: Note that max throughput is now 20k messages per second and can be increased by contacting Azure support, per the link above.

Comment: Sorry, never mind, that's per storage account.  Rate of 2k messages per second remains (assuming <1kB messages): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-queue-storage-scale-targets

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can make a more robust mechanism by passing a [`QueryRequestOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.queuerequestoptions.aspx) to `AddMessageAsync`.

Before the query is sent, the request message adds these properties to the command.

I would try passing `QueryRequestOptions` and setting a value to [`MaximumExecutionTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.queuerequestoptions.maximumexecutiontime.aspx) and [`ServerTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.queuerequestoptions.servertimeout.aspx) with a larger value.

This is how the request is filled prior to being sent:

```
// Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.QueueRequestOptions
internal void ApplyToStorageCommand<T>(RESTCommand<T> cmd)
{
    if (this.LocationMode.HasValue)
    {
        cmd.LocationMode = this.LocationMode.Value;
    }
    if (this.ServerTimeout.HasValue)
    {
        cmd.ServerTimeoutInSeconds = new int?((int)this.ServerTimeout.Value.TotalSeconds);
    }
    if (this.OperationExpiryTime.HasValue)
    {
        cmd.OperationExpiryTime = this.OperationExpiryTime;
        return;
    }
    if (this.MaximumExecutionTime.HasValue)
    {
        cmd.OperationExpiryTime = new DateTime?(DateTime.Now + this.MaximumExecutionTime.Value);
    }
}
```

And this is how it's sent:

```
rESTCommand.PreProcessResponse = delegate(RESTCommand<NullType> cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
{
    HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException<NullType>(HttpStatusCode.Created, resp, NullType.Value, cmd, ex);
    return NullType.Value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach to minimize the chance for a timeout, however I wanted to understand what caused the timeout in the first place.